# Matlab - Integer Comparison Error

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to compare integers in a `while` loop, shown below:

```
Sigma_Wanted_Start = 0.000;
Sigma_Wanted_End   = 0.009;
Sigma_Increment    = 0.001;
Sigma_Current      = 0.000;

while (Sigma_Wanted_End ~= Sigma_Current)
    Sigma_Current = Sigma_Current + Sigma_Increment;
end
```

If `Sigma_Wanted_End == 0.009`, then we would stop the for loop. The problem is that the statement is shown `true` even if `Sigma_Wanted_End == Sigma_Current`.

Another strange thing is that if `Sigma_Wanted_End == 0.008`, then the while loop would stop.

I thought it's the difference between integers, and `double`, so I used `double` on all the numbers, but the problem still occurred.

Does anybody know why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Those values do not look like integers to me.

Comment: Sigma_Current was 0 without decimals, so I added 0.000 just to see if the problem persisted. But the problem is still there.

Comment: You won't succeed doing this with floating point numbers. See e.g. http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/ for a more elaborate explanation. And, as an aside, writing `x = 0` does not result in `x` being an integer datatype.

Comment: Sure looks like you could convert that into a `for`-loop, which would be free of this particular problem...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not test for exact equality when comparing floating point values, due to the finite precision available. Instead do something like this:

```
while (Sigma_Current < Sigma_Wanted_End)
    Sigma_Current = Sigma_Current + Sigma_Increment;
end
```

Comment: Somehow I did not think of this earlier! Thanks for your help! Now I know that I should be more careful with floating point values.

Answer (score 1):

floating point representations in matlab are not equal because of rounding problems.

let say if we have

```
x = 0.3
 0.4-0.1
 x==y
```

this will give you false 
so you could do this

```
Sigma_Wanted_Start = 0.000;
Sigma_Wanted_End = 0.009;
Sigma_Increment = 0.001;
Sigma_Current = 0.000;
while (~((Sigma_Wanted_End - Sigma_Current)<0.0))
    Sigma_Current = Sigma_Current + Sigma_Increment;
end
```